# How to change the "0°" position of a Knob in Snap.svg Library

Tags: math, rotation, atan2

I created a Knob (basically a circle) using the Snap.svg library which I rotate  using Snap's transform function and rotate parameter. 
I use two Snap built in functions, `Snap.deg()`  and `Snap.angle()` to rotate the knob to a certain position (so that the "hand" faces the cursor or a touch point).  My understanding is that `Snap.angle` works very similarly to the atan2 function, while `Snap.deg` converts a radian value to degrees

The issue I am having is that by default, the 0 / 360° position is when the hand of the knob (like the hour hand) is facing 3:00 and (the degrees go up when you move the knob clockwise)  I want the 0 / 360° position to be when the hour hand is at 6:00 (with the degrees still going up for clockwise rotation).

I tried to just add subtract 90° but that just makes the value inaccurate because from 3:00 and 6:00 the angle calculated is between 0 and -90.

These values are important not because of how the physical knob looks (the current calculations work for that) but because I am using the calculated values elsewhere in the code and want a value of 0 for due south, 90 for due west, 180 for due north etc.

The reference for Snap.deg is: http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.angle

Comment: Please be a bit more specific on what exactly it is that does not work. Your approach seems to be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "normal" cartesian coordinates and trig operations use:

```
x = cos(theta)
y = sin(theta)
```

and make zero degrees go along the positive X axis, and points sweep *anticlockwise* as *theta* increases.

To start at the "6 o'clock" position and rotate *clockwise* instead, you need:

```
x = -sin(theta)
y = -cos(theta)
```

i.e. x and y swapped, and negated.

Hence, to get theta from x and y, use:

```
theta = atan2(-x, -y);    // usually y, x
```

Answer (score 0):

If `atan2(y, x)` gives you an angle, with 0 for east and π/2 for north, then `atan2(x, -y)` will give you an angle with 0 for south and π/2 for east. If you want π/2 west, as Alnitak mentioned in a comment, simply replace `x` by `-x`, and you get `atan2(-x, -y)`.

Comment: knobs usually rotate _clockwise_, so `π/2` should be _west_.

Comment: I see. I should have been more clear, I am looking to less change the value of the rotation, (my graphics library depends on the number) but instead "map" the values (after they are calculated) to get it in a different range. Any idea here?

Comment: @Startec: Please edit your question to make it more clear. In particular, please outline what libraries you use, where and how you obtain the value and where the library depends on it. Also indicate exactly what orientation you get and what orientation you want.